# Replace a widget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, inheritance, qwidget

I have a base class which has some gui items that i have set positions of using the designer in Qt creator. Those items are:

```
QWidget* w1;
QWidget* w2;
QWidget* w3;
```

Now in a class that inherits that base class, I would like to "transform" those widgets into lineEdit items, that would keep all the geometrical parameters of that widgets. So I do something like this:

```
QLineEdit* leAmplitude;
leAmplitude = new QLineEdit(ui->w1);
leAmplitude->setGeometry(ui->w1->geometry());
ui->glControls->addWidget(leAmplitude);
```

But the added `QLineEdit` item doesn't appear in the exact same place as w1 item. Its just added at the bottom of other controls in the `QGridLayout` glControls. How to make the lineEdit to take all geometric parameters from w1?

Comment: Did you set w1 as not visible ?

Comment: I did not. Is it like that by default?

Comment: I'd say it's true by default. It inherits the visibility of the parent.

Answer (score 12):

Layout takes care of the widgets placed in the layout, according to the hints given by the widget, so calling `setGeometry`, then doing `addLayout` is not useful. Also, adding widget to layout resets it parent, so you setting new widget's parent to `ui->w1` is not useful either.

Fortunately, there is [QLayout::replaceWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#replaceWidget) method! Just use that. Example:

```
QLineEdit* leAmplitude;
leAmplitude = new QLineEdit;
QLayoutItem *previous = ui->glControls->replaceWidget(ui->w1, leAmplitude);
// possibly assert that previous is ui->w1, or just delete it, or whatever
```

This method was added as late as in Qt 5.2 it seems, so if you need to support older versions, I can expand this answer to cover how to (try to) do the same manually. But in short, you have to use the [right QGridLayout::addWidget overload](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget) and make sure relevant properties (including at least `sizeHint` and `sizePolicy`) match.

Answer (score 3):

try this, it is works:

```
QLineEdit* leAmplitude;
leAmplitude = new QLineEdit(ui->w1->parentWidget());
ui->w1->parentWidget()->layout()->replaceWidget(ui->w1, leAmplitude);
ui->w1 = leAmplitude;
```