# Qtdesigner connection between MainWindow and multiple Forms

Tags: qt5, qt-designer, qt5.15

I am new to Qt, and trying to build Gui.
I have a simple question but i can't find any answer to it.

My Gui consist of MainWindow and some number of Forms.

Gui should work as follows:

Where is a QListWidget in MainWindow with some records.
If user click on record in this list, in MainWindow should pop up Form for that exact record.

Each record has own Form. And all Forms have different number of widgets inside. But all Forms are Qwidget.
So if User pick List_item_1 - Form_for_list_item_1 should appear.
If User pick List_item_2 - Form_for_list_item_2 should appear.
And so on.

"Name" of records is defined, so user can not add to QListWidget record with random name. Only pre-defined records (in this context List_item_1, List_item_2, ... , List_item_n)

After that, if user click on next record - the prev. Form should be replaced by next Form.
But i can not understand how to connect MainWindow and FORMS.

MainWindow:
[MainWindow_brief](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPvIf.png)

Form:
[Form_template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJqyy.png)

Expected result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mh3H.png)

I am using Qt 5.15.2 (2020).

I have tried "signals and slots", but i can't connect them to Form. Simply QtDesigner won't let me choose Form.
I have tried "Promote to...", but it didn't work.

Comment: (*If user click on record in this list, in MainWindow should pop up Form for that exact record*). Do you mean that the input widgets in the form should be updated with the data from the clicked item?

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayeneMihoub
No, not widgets but whole Form should be replaced. I have From_1, Form_2 and so on. All Forms have different structure, but all of them are QWidget

Comment: Perhaps you need a [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstackedwidget.html).

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayeneMihoub , QStackedWidget - not the best option, because it allows the user to switch between pages within the widget. And I don't want to allow that, because it can get confusing in the user's head. It should be specifically  List_item_1 - Form_for_list_Item_1

Comment: (*it allows the user to switch between pages within the widget.*), if you mean the arrows, then they're only visible in Qt Designer and preview mode, try running the app, they won't be there, so users have no way to switch pages unless you provide a way to do so.

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayeneMihoub okay, i didn't know about arrows, but if i understand how QStackedWidget works - it would load all Forms at the program start. And it isn't a good thing at all according https://stackoverflow.com/a/70399326/22509100

Comment: I don't know how many forms you will be using and how they are made and loaded so I can't say. Here's another approach: connect the `itemClicked` signal to a custom slot where you use [QLayout::replaceWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlayout.html#replaceWidget) as demonstrated here: [Replace a widget in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382622/replace-a-widget-in-qt).

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayeneMihoub , hm... I think it'll work, but I'll have to test it. Thank you!